# Ionic 2 search bar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm implementig a search bar, it filters the way I want, but after 2 seconds, it shows the whole array again, and I dont really understand why.

Thanks for your help.

This is the .ts

```
  getCatalog() {
    this.http.get('url', {}, {}).then(data => {
      console.log("Data:", JSON.parse(data.data));
      this.catalogList = JSON.parse(data.data);

      // console.log(data.status);
      // console.log(data.data); // data received by server
      // console.log(data.headers);

    })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

      });
  }




  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items

    this.getCatalog();
    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;
    //console.log("VALUE", ev);

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.catalogList = this.catalogList.filter((item) => {
        console.log("ITEM", item)
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

This is where i have the *ngFor

```
   <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let item of catalogList">
Other code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your HTTP request finishs after you've already filtered your array, this'll make the `catalogList` receive the parsed JSON after you've filtered, this is why it resets.

Do you really need to get your catalog from the server every time the ser types something in the searchbar? Is your catalog that dynamic? If not you can simply save it in your `catalogList` when the user enters the page and create another object to be used at your filter:

```
public catalogListFiltered: any[] = []; // CREATE A NEW VARIABLE THAT'LL BE USED ON YOUR NGFOR

  ionViewDidEnter() { // or ionViewDidLoad, depends on what lifecycle you need
    this.http.get('url', {}, {}).then(data => {
      this.catalogList = JSON.parse(data.data);
      this.initializeCatalogs();
    });
  }

  // THIS'LL SET YOUR FILTERED ARRAY TO THE FIRST/FULL VERSION OF YOUR CATALOG
  initializeCatalogs(){
    this.catalogListFiltered = this.catalogList;
  }


  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items

    this.initializeCatalogs();
    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;
    //console.log("VALUE", ev);

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.catalogList = this.catalogList.filter((item) => {
        console.log("ITEM", item)
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

If you really need to call your API everytime to get your catalog just work with promises

```
  getCatalog = (): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
      this.http.get('url', {}, {}).then(data => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data.data));
      });
    });
  }

  // maybe this'll have the same effect as the above, maybe someone can say if that'll work with some changes on your 'getItem' method:
  // getCatalog(){ return this.http.get('url', {}, {}); };

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items

    this.getCatalog().then(res => {
      this.catalogList = res;
      // set val to the value of the searchbar
      let val = ev.target.value;
      //console.log("VALUE", ev);

      // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
      if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        this.catalogList = this.catalogList.filter((item) => {
          return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.